# API Race conditions

Tags: java, design, architecture, javascript, conditions

I have an API in which we expect a emailID and a certain deal data. 
The case is we want to keep the dealId and contactId(email) to be unique. 
Creating a deal requires data insertion in multiple tables.

data is first inserted in tb_contact_email.
Then , it is inserted in tb_deals , tb_contacts and tb_contact_details

If two deal creation hits come simultaneously from the same contact , the second hit is able to ascertain that tb_contact_email record exists. However,the second hit is not able to find the record in tb_deals because the first call is still in the process.

We cannot ignore the second hit because we expect to create a note related to that deal from the second hit.
How to handle this architecture problem.

Answer (score 6):

That's what database transactions were invented for. All modifications during a transaction are either written to the database at once on commit, or none are written in case they would conflict with a parallel transaction. If your transaction fails due to a conflict, you will need to retry the operation from the start using the new consistent database state.

Answer (score 0):

[**bold** emphasis mine]

> data is **first** inserted in tb_contact_email. **Then** , it is inserted in tb_deals , tb_contacts and tb_contact_details

That right there is your whole problem. The data shouldn't be **first** inserted here and **then** inserted there. It should be inserted here **and** there at the **same time**.